# Detect the objects from a low light image

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing

I want to detect the similar objects from an image. It is a low light image. Currently I am using template matching. But it is not properly detect all the objects.

Comment: Don't worry, this is normal.

Comment: Use histogram equalization to stretch the pixel intensities and then proceed